# Not able to Add or Update table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I am trying to insert and update table using Entity Framework 6. I am not able to do it.

When i insert, I get an error

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'SampleV2' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation

When I update, the error thrown is:

> The property 'Name' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

My code:

```
//Table script
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleV2](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

// SampletV2.cs
public partial class SampleV2
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
}

// Utilities.cs
public static Dictionary<bool,string> SavePlayerDetails(SampleV2 model)
{
            Dictionary<bool, string> dicInfo = new Dictionary<bool, string>();

            if (model.Id == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    SampleV2 sam = new SampleV2
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
                        Status = model.Status
                    };

                    using (var _context = new ExamEntities1())
                    {
                        _context.SampleV2.Add(sam);
                        _context.SaveChanges(); // getting error here
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }                
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var _context = new ExamEntities1())
                    {
                        SampleV2 data = _context.SampleV2.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == model.Id);
                        data.DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth;
                        data.Name = model.Name;
                        data.Status = model.Status;
                        _context.Entry(data).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; // getting error here
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }                
            }            

            return dicInfo;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `id` as primary key in DB and `KeyAttribute`, since the error indicates missing primary key on target table.

Comment: Model has been created dynamically, do i want to add KeyAttribute manually?

Comment: Do you have a composite PK?

Comment: No,i dont have composite PK

Comment: Have you using EDMX? Try adding primary key on both database and model - note that EF supports one primary key and not composite (more than 1 primary key at the same table).

Comment: Yes i am using EDMX. Database is having PK on Id field

Comment: I have added my table structure, kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you using Database First, the error indicates that the `SampleV2` entity or table missing a primary key field or it is not being set in model class.

Try adding `KeyAttribute` on `id` entity to mark it as primary key field:

```
public partial class SampleV2
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, you need to add primary key in DB using table designer with `Set Primary Key` and setting `StoreGeneratedPattern` as `Identity` in EDMX file, then update generated model from database to ensure mapped entity class has identity primary key field.

NB: The `KeyAttribute` can be generated automatically by editing T4 template (`.tt`) file like this:

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
// -- other stuff

var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
if (simpleProperties.Any())
{
    foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
    {
         if (ef.IsKey(edmProperty)) { 
    #>    [Key]
    <#    } 
    #>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
    <#
    }
}
```

Similar issues:

[Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583770/unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquery-and-no-updatefu)

[Entity Framework 4 Error: Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471331/entity-framework-4-error-unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-defini)

[Why am I getting a "Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery..." exception when trying to update a model in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774871/why-am-i-getting-a-unable-to-update-the-entityset-because-it-has-a-definingquer)

Comment: StoreGeneratedPattern already set into Identity only. KeyAttribute only not creating

Comment: Thanks for your effect, after doing "Update Model from Database" also not changing Id field into KeyAttribute

Comment: If your model generation using T4, I already give how to add `KeyAttribute` automatically every model update on EDMX file in latter part above. Check this doc for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4414/database-first-model-generation/27049/adding-data-annotations-to-the-generated-model.